# Displaying records from two tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables in PHPMyAdmin as the following:

Table 1: `magazine_buys`

| name | price | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Milk | 13 | 2023-02-05 |
| Bread | 10 | 2023-02-10 |

Table 2: `magazine_sells`

| name | price1 | price2 | pur_date | sold_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Onion | 4 | 6 | 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-06 |
| Pumpkin | 8 | 10 | 2023-02-02 | 2023-02-09 |

I want to make a query that will give me a table like this

| name | price | price2 | date | sold date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Onion | 4 | 6 | 2023-02-01 | 2023-02-06 |
| Pumpkin | 8 | 10 | 2023-02-02 | 2023-02-09 |
| Milk | 13 | NULL | 2023-02-05 | NULL |
| Bread | 10 | NULL | 2023-02-10 | NULL |

The first problem is that in one table we have the value 'price' and in the other `price1`, I tried to do it with the same name set in as `price p` but it duplicated the records

```
SELECT coalesce(magazine_buys.name, magazine_sells.name),
       coalesce(magazine_buys.price, magazine_sells.price1),
       coalesce(magazine_buys.date, magazine_sells.pur_date) 
FROM magazine_sells, magazine_buys;
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION` like so...

```
SELECT
    name,
    price1 as price,
    price2,
    pur_date as `date`,
    sold_date
FROM magazine_sells
UNION
SELECT
    name,
    price,
    NULL,
    `date`,
    NULL
FROM magazine_buys;
```

[Click here to go to demo in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/359592/1)

Bear in mind that `UNION` will remove any duplicate rows. If you want to keep any duplicates, then use `UNION ALL`.